# Alternative to filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)

Tags: php, email

Is there an alternative to `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`?

Because it doesn't seem to recognize cases such us american@hotmail (without .com for instance) as invalid address.

MY CODE:

```
$c = 0;
$email = $_POST["ml"];
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
   $c = 1; // Email non valida
}
```

Comment: you can use Regx but what the problem with this ? its working fine [without .com](http://codepad.org/wixegCSq) and [with .com](http://codepad.org/kZviTlM8)

Comment: Actually `american@hotmail` is a valid email address...

Comment: `$var = 'american@hotmail';var_dump(filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));` returns false.

Comment: The problem is that if I try to send an email (to an email address passed by the user throw an HTML form) without a complete domain the DNS don't know where deliver the message

Comment: What's the content of ```$_POST["ml"]``` ? Make a [var_dump()](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) on it.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably made something wrong, because it does recognize such adress as invalid. Just try [by yourself](http://www.functions-online.com/filter_var.html).

Comment: You are right. Good web site. Thanks now I'll find what is the problem

Comment: I writen it in my QUESTION